# Does replication in couchdb affects the _changes feed?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-2.x

We are using CouchDB (v 2.3.1).

We have a replication to copy the data from one server to another. The source server will also keep getting new data from time to time.

I am working on a similar algorithm mentioned below:

```
1. read /dbname/_changes
2. process each row idempotently
3. periodically (every X seconds or every X rows) store the "seq" value of the last row you processed

If you ever crash, or if you weren't using continuous=true, you can do this same procedure again but modified in step 1;

revised 1. read /dbname/_changes?since=X

where X is the value you saved in step 3. If you're not using continuous mode then you could just record the "last_seq" value at the end of consuming the non-continuous response.
```

Reference: [Algo reference](https://lists.apache.org/thread/z79yxo9bmxwy4xdpfybx5vhmt47z12tl)

Question - 1
In this scenario, does the replication affect the _changes feed maintained by CouchDB?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, IF you're reading the target DB `_changes`, then yes a replication from source to that DB will change the `_changes` feed of that target DB.

If you're asking whether your act of reading the `_changes` feed will impact or be impacted by the replication reading the `_changes` feed, then no. The read operation doesn't change the state of the server/DB in any way.

To clarify the `seq`/`last_seq` is unchanged by reads, and continuous replications maintain their own state of the `last_seq` they processed, see `/_scheduler/docs` [more here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/replicator.html#basics).

Comment: Smarty, 
Observed some times, /dbname/_changes?since=X gives older changes before "X" last_seq from target db. Did you face the same issue? If yes, what could be the best approach to handle, if you know?

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question, you should mark this as accepted and create a new question with the details.

Comment: Yes Smarty, created separate ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843905/does-couchdb-changessince-x-request-give-older-feed-before-x.

Comment: Halfway there...